# enter key press event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**This is Not working**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="newtopic" placeholder="Add Topic">
```

**Script**

```
$(document).bind('keypress',function(){
$("#newtopic").keydown(function(e){ 
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
}); });
```

Comment: Have you tried $("#newtopic").keyup

Comment: it's working:: http://jsfiddle.net/a46p6/1/

Comment: your code is already working (check @C-link 's fiddle)

Comment: Not Working with me, alert is not popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#newtopic").keypress(function(e){ 
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
 }); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xN57C/)

Comment: Can you share fiddle to identify the problem?

Comment: hey its working now i have downloaded the jquery 2.0.2
I think path **//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js** was not working

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is still not working you may try:

```
if(e.keyCode==13 || e.which == 13) // for cross browser
```

Comment: what browser you are using and do you put your code in $(document).ready()?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#newtopic").keypress(function(e){ 
               if(e.keyCode==13 || e.which == 13){
                alert("Hello World");
               }
               }); 
              });

Comment: I think you are using same id more than on time in the document. you may also check the fiddle for the same using the jquery library 1.6: http://jsfiddle.net/xN57C/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issues with your script stack order. you have to load jquery first then add your script below the specified library:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#newtopic").keydown(function(e){ 
           if(e.keyCode==13){
                alert("Hello World");
           }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```